# How to find a specific patch for a kernel file

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, patch, version-control

I've been debugging an issue in my linux kernel and have found a fix for the issue. Checking cross reference, I can see that the fix was applied to that file between kernel version A and kernel version B.

What is the best way to find the patch the exact patch that this fix got checked in with? I would like to see if there are other issues that are fixed with the same patch.

Thing I know:

- Exact file and line of code that changed
- Kernel version where the bug was present and the version that it was fixed in

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get somewhere browsing the [torvalds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/time/hrtimer.c) git tree, eg for the file `time/hrtimer.c`. Click on *blame* and for each line number you see the last patch applied. You can also browse the *history* for older patches.